# How to control a horizontal scroll with buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The idea is that when I click the button, the scroll should move in the direction I clicked while the button is held down. It was working on the first try, but suddenly stopped working.

```
export default function initCarousel() {
  const carousel = document.querySelector("[data-carousel='scroll']");
  const rightBtn = document.querySelector("[data-carousel='right']");
  const leftBtn = document.querySelector("[data-carousel='left']");

  let timer;
  leftBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      carousel.scrollLeft -= 50;
    }, 20);
  });

  rightBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      carousel.scrollLeft += 50;
    }, 20);
  });

  leftBtn.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
  });

  rightBtn.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
  });
}
```

Comment: I discovered what the problem was. I had forgotten to remove the "scroll-behavior: smooth" property.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct for handling the horizontal scroll with buttons on mouse down events. However, it could have stopped working for a variety of reasons. Here are some items to look into and think about:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  initCarousel();
});

function initCarousel() {
  const carousel = document.querySelector("[data-carousel='scroll']");
  const rightBtn = document.querySelector("[data-carousel='right']");
  const leftBtn = document.querySelector("[data-carousel='left']");

  let timer;

  leftBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      carousel.scrollLeft -= 50;
    }, 20);
  });

  rightBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      carousel.scrollLeft += 50;
    }, 20);
  });

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    if (timer) clearInterval(timer);
  });
}
```